# Can't copy contents to my iPad or iPhone

Tags: ios

I can't seem to be able to transfer files from my laptop (which has Pop!_OS 19.10) to my iOS devices. Specifically, while copying the file to any of my apps on iPad/iPhone (inside Documents on iPad/iPhone), the progress indicator on the file manager seems stuck and doesn't move forward at all after pasting the file. (See below).

[image]

I can, however, do it the other way around - copy files from my iPad to my laptop.

Using the same cable and device, I can do transfers from a Windows machine so I'm guessing the problem is not with my iPad(I recently updated to iOS 13) or my cables. I have also tried it on multiple USB ports.

My device seems paired with my laptop since trying

```
idevicepair pair
```

gave me

```
SUCCESS: Paired with device XYZ
```

How can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to stop the sharing between all your devices, then on any one device, go to Settings>icloud and turn off the services you don't want that device to share/sync. Or turn off icloud altogether if that's what you want.